# Raspberry pi I2S MEMS Microphone Right CHN Mono Using pyaudio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, microphone, pyaudio, digital

I am using Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone Breakout for recording. ref. https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout?view=all

When i wire the Mic to RPI in Mono configuration as per below image I am able record audio using arecord command and below python code

[image]

> > arecord -D dmic_sv -c2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v recording.wav

Python Code snippet:

channels=1, rate=48000, frames_per_buffer=2400

```
def start_recording(self):
        try:
            self.logger.info("start_recording()> enter")
            # Use a stream with a callback in non-blocking mode
            self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt32,
                                            channels=self.channels,
                                            rate=self.rate,
                                            input=True,
                                            frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer,
                                            stream_callback=self.get_callback())
            self._stream.start_stream()
            self.logger.info("start_recording()> exit")
            return self
        except Exception, e:
            self.logger.error("start_recording()>", exc_info = True)
```

But If I connect channel selection pin to logic high vltage i am able to record audio using arecord command but uanble to record using python code.
Any changes required in python code to record right channel mono audio?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but using [python-sounddevice](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice). Here's my [repo](https://github.com/kpolley/Python_AVrecorder)

EDIT:
here is the specific audio recording class for clarification

```
import threading
import queue
import numpy
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

class AudioRecorder():

    def __init__(self):

        self.open = True
        self.file_name = 'name_of_file.wav'
        self.channels = 1
        self.q = queue.Queue()

        # Get samplerate
        device_info = sd.query_devices(2, 'input')
        self.samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):

        # This is called (from a separate thread) for each audio block.
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        self.q.put(indata.copy())

    def record(self):
        with sf.SoundFile(self.file_name, mode='x', samplerate=self.samplerate, channels=self.channels) as file:
            with sd.InputStream(samplerate=self.samplerate, channels=self.channels, callback=self.callback):

                while(self.open == True):
                    file.write(self.q.get())
```

EDIT 2: The code is a Python Class that creates an audio file using an I2S microphone similar to the image shown in the question. While the value `self.open` is true, sounddevice will write the audio data into a queue (`def callback`) and then write the data into a file. All you have to do is toggle `self.open` to start and stop recording.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for taking the previous feedback on board and providing the code from the link into the answer. Now to make this a good answer, it would be great if you could provide some explanation to the code, to help future readers :). (Also, it looks like some of your formatting is a little off)